# Limit the no.of rows in table(Ms-word)

Tags: ms-word

I created a table with 2 column and 5 rows in Ms-word .If i press tab button in last row of last column(4,1) the row will expand (ie.new row will added).I want to fix the no.of rows.

Answer (score 2):

set word file in the protection mode then no one can edit the table.

1. Insert table in the MS word
2. Click on review in the top nav.
3. Click on Restrict editing
4. In restrictions format and Editing windows select Allow only this type of editing only check box

[image: Check the image]